# How to get some parts of the directory c#

Tags: c#

For example,

```
foreach (var imageFile in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //add to list
}
```

Output of imageFile = `C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb\Slide\Main\slider2.png`

I need to get only `\Slide\Main\slider2.png`

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: How do you decide which part to discard? Why not just remove the directory path from the image path? eg `imageFile.Remove(dir);`

Comment: Well, what's the rule that should be used?  For that one case, you can split the path based on `MyWeb` maybe, but what about other directories?  Is there a common place where it's split?

Comment: It depends on how exactly this part should be determined. Is it always four folder in path or something else?

Comment: @DavidG -- How can you close this as a dupe when we don't have enough information yet?

Comment: @rory.ap well it should always split at \Slide\

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i just need the second to the last folder up to the filename

Comment: @AndyKorneyev does always splitting it \Slide\ counts? because \Slide\ folder name does not change.

Comment: @megatron Are you trying to make all of your image paths relative to the `C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb` folder?

Comment: @DavidG no, it varies. it is just the folder from \Slide\Main does not change.

Comment: @megatron find the index of the nth slash and get the rest of the string with `.Substring()`

Comment: @megatron If you know which files you need already, why should you search the whole directory? I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a specific folder, you can do this:

```
var imageFile = @"C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb\Slide\Main\slider2.png";
var subFolder = @"\Slide\Main";

var relativePath = imageFile.Substring(
    imageFile.IndexOf(subFolder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
string imageFile = @"C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb\Slide\Main\slider2.png";
string match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(imageFile,@"\\Slide\\Main\\.*").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using string.Split("\") and that will give you all the chunks of that path and then you can concatenate the rest from the position you want, or use a Regular Expressionn as @Zalomon said

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Uri easily, I have tested it, So it is Working fine

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Uri uriAddress1 = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Documents\\MyWeb\\Slide\\Main\\slider2.png");
            Console.WriteLine("The parts are {0}{1}{2}", uriAddress1.Segments[5], uriAddress1.Segments[6], uriAddress1.Segments[7]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could credit the person who wrote this first, but I've since lost the link.

From my utilities collection:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a Relative Path for targetPath, from basePath
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="basePath">The Directory to start from.</param>
    /// <param name="targetPath">Full Path to file or folder that is to be made relative</param>
    /// <returns>The relative location of targetPath, from basePath</returns>
    /// <remarks>Tested in Util.Tests.IO.PathUtilsTests</remarks>
    public static string MakeRelativePath(string basePath, string targetPath)
    {
        if (basePath == targetPath)
            return "";

        if (!basePath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
            basePath += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(basePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException("basePath");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetPath)) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetPath");

        var fromUri = new Uri(basePath);
        var toUri = new Uri(targetPath);

        if (fromUri.Scheme != toUri.Scheme) { return targetPath; } // path can't be made relative.

        var relativeUri = fromUri.MakeRelativeUri(toUri);
        var relativePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(relativeUri.ToString());

        if (toUri.Scheme.Equals("file", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            relativePath = relativePath.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        }

        return relativePath;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var output = @"C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb\Slide\Main\slider2.png";
var basePath = @"C:\Users\Documents\MyWeb\";

var rel = MakeRelativePath(basePath, output);
```

Comment: Yes! That looks like where I first got this from.